# Find the equation of the plane through the point

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of the plane through the point P=(4,3,3) and parallel to the plane 2x−2y−z=−4.

I did 2(x-4)-2(y-3)-(z-3)=-4 which gave me a final response of z=2x-2y+5. It is wrong.

Comment: Please start accepting answers; I looked through your other questions and none of them have accepted answers. Accepting answers resolves a question, so other people know that the answer is correct.

Comment: And also learn how to format. This is the fourth question you are asking without proper format...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 
$$2(x-4)-2(y-3)-(z-3)=0$$
not 
$$2(x-4)-2(y-3)-(z-3)=-4$$
You can think of finding planes through points like finding all points perpendicular to a particular vector in this case it would be
$$<2,-2,-1>\cdot<x-4,y-3,z-3>=0$$
(because when two vectors are dotted and equal zero, they are perpendicular).

Comment: You are right! Thank youuu

Answer (score 0):

Find a vector $v$ that is normal to the first plane (hint: this should be easy).

Then $v$ should be perpendicular to the normal of your desired plane (think about why this is the case)

Find a vector normal to $v$ and use it to plug in the values $a, b,$ and $c$ in the scalar equation of your desired plane (given by $ax+by+cz+d=0$)

Plug in the given point to find $d$. All done.